# How to print a specific part of page that have javascript

Tags: javascript, printing

I tried to print a part of my page but the problem is it only displays the html and doesn't show the JavaScript; I don't know why. In the print the thing that was implemented in JavaScript does not appeare

EDIT: removed the code and provided a full example in the link.
this is an example of what i mean. the javascript used to create the game will not be shown in the print.

```js
var myGamePiece;
var myObstacles = [];
var myScore;

function startGame() {
  myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
  myGamePiece.gravity = 0.05;
  myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 40, "text");
  myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
  canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
  start: function() {
    this.canvas.width = 480;
    this.canvas.height = 270;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.frameNo = 0;
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
  },
  clear: function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
  this.type = type;
  this.score = 0;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.speedX = 0;
  this.speedY = 0;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.gravity = 0;
  this.gravitySpeed = 0;
  this.update = function() {
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    if (this.type == "text") {
      ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
    } else {
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
  }
  this.newPos = function() {
    this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
    this.x += this.speedX;
    this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
    this.hitBottom();
  }
  this.hitBottom = function() {
    var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
    if (this.y > rockbottom) {
      this.y = rockbottom;
      this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    }
  }
  this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
    var myleft = this.x;
    var myright = this.x + (this.width);
    var mytop = this.y;
    var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
    var otherleft = otherobj.x;
    var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
    var othertop = otherobj.y;
    var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
    var crash = true;
    if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
      crash = false;
    }
    return crash;
  }
}

function updateGameArea() {
  var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
  for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
    if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
      return;
    }
  }
  myGameArea.clear();
  myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
  if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
    x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
    minHeight = 20;
    maxHeight = 200;
    height = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxHeight - minHeight + 1) + minHeight);
    minGap = 50;
    maxGap = 200;
    gap = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxGap - minGap + 1) + minGap);
    myObstacles.push(new component(10, height, "green", x, 0));
    myObstacles.push(new component(10, x - height - gap, "green", x, height + gap));
  }
  for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
    myObstacles[i].x += -1;
    myObstacles[i].update();
  }
  myScore.text = "SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
  myScore.update();
  myGamePiece.newPos();
  myGamePiece.update();
}

function everyinterval(n) {
  if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function accelerate(n) {
  myGamePiece.gravity = n;
}

function myFunction() {
  var prtContent = document.getElementById("page");
  var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
  WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
  WinPrint.document.close();
  WinPrint.focus();
  WinPrint.print();
  WinPrint.close();
}

window.onload=startGame;
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<div id="page">
  <button onmousedown="accelerate(-0.2)" onmouseup="accelerate(0.05)">ACCELERATE</button>
  <p>Use the ACCELERATE button to stay in the air</p>
  <p>How long can you stay alive?</p>
  <input type="button" onClick="myFunction()" class="button" value="Print this page">
</div>
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] - we need to see what you mean by "the thing that implemented in javascript" means - I guess you mean dynamically added html, but am not sure

Comment: you have not added any page link to the window.open function

Comment: @rahul - what do you mean? There is no need for a "page link" in the code above

Comment: i tried the same code and its working....

Comment: @rahul 
 
 
it will work right but it only shows the html button and other html code. i am doing a game in javascript this print code does not show the game it does not print it. i hope you understand what i mean

Comment: Apart from testing if the popup exists, you need to copy the canvas to the popup. See the duplicate I posted. also your canvas is inserted BEFORE the page div you try to print

Answer (score -1):

I have tried the code in this way and its working fine

```
<div id="page">Test test test test test test</div>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var prtContent = document.getElementById("page");
var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
WinPrint.document.close();
WinPrint.focus();
WinPrint.print();
WinPrint.close();

}
myFunction();
</script>
```

Comment: it will work right but it only shows the html button and other html code. i am doing a game in javascript this print code does not show the game it does not print it. i hope you understand what i mean

Comment: so in case please put your complete code